# How to append an enum represented by a series of hex values to QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qbytearray

I have some enums which are represented by series of hex values in the following manner:

```
enum someEnum
{
    NameA = 0x2121,
    NameB = 0x2223,
    NameC = 0x2020
};
```

I want to append one of these enums to QByteArray in the following way:

```
QByteArray anArray;
anArray.append(NameA);
```

But this approach produces the warning

```
implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 8481 to 33.
```

In fact, even if I do the following:

```
anArray.append(static_cast<char>(NameA));
```

it only appends 0x21 (in decimal 33).

I also tried doing the following:

```
const char * t = reinterpret_cast<char*>(NameA);
anArray.append(t, sizeof(t));
```

but that leads to a segmentation fault.

I could of course do the following without any loss of value or crash or any other problem:

```
anArray.append(0x21);
anArray.append(0x21);
```

But I don't want that, I want to directly append the enum. Could you please suggest a correct way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hex, octal, decimal, binary, *<whatever base>* representation *doesn't* matter. That's just different ways to write the same number.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I didn't say it matters, I just can't figure why QByteArray cannot append the value correctly.

Comment: Because QByteArray operates with individual *bytes* (actually `char` but doesn't matter here) and the individual values of your `enum` all exceed what a single byte can represent. It doesn't *interpret* the data, it doesn't know *what* it stores - it's just a byte stream. So to store your `enum` values in it you need to convert them to a series of bytes. And btw, saying "How to append a hex represented enum to QByteArray?" kind of *does* say that you think the hex representation matters.

Comment: So, is there a way where I can append mutilple bytes?

Comment: Yes. Read [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html), particularly the various overloads of `append`, `prepend`, `push_back` and `insert`. Also, as mentioned below in an answer, look at [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can use QDataStream:

```
QByteArray byteArray;
QDataStream dataStream(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

dataStream << NameA;
```

Sorry, but I do not have qt available right now and i cannot tested this

Comment: I tested it :) theres a small problem, not sure if it's ok for you: it does not store `0x2121`, but `0x002121`... probably because of the size of an enum... in c++11 you can set the size of an enum class object: `enum smallenum: int16_t`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that it adds a 00, but I have tested and it doesn't cause any issues as of now, let's see what happens after further testing.

Comment: Note that by default `QDataStream` uses big endian (it is configurable). Also [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) recommend to use types of predefined size, so casting to `qint16 ` is recommended (when writing and reading).

Comment: @MarekR Thanks, this info helped a good deal. After casting as `short` (aka `qint16` in qt), it doesn't add that 00 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
QByteArray byteArray;
// this will store the integer as a hex value
byteArray.append(QByteArray::number(NameA, 16));
// this will store the integer as a base 10 value
byteArray.append(QByteArray::number(NameA));
```

Comment: There's something odd with this code, it does not compile.

Comment: Sorry I missed the append function call